# Есть два класса:

Tags: python-3.x

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, surname, name, patronymic, birthday, phone):
        self.author = surname
        self.name = name
        self.year = patronymic
        self.shelve = birthday
        self.shelve = phone

class Employees(People):
    def __init__(self, surname, name, patronymic, birthday, phone, id, code, salary):
        super.__init__(surname, name, patronymic, birthday, phone)
        self.id = id
        self.code = code
        self.salary = salary
```

А также метод вывода всей информации на экран:

```
def printer(self):
    print(f"Surname: {self.surname}, Name: {self.name}, Patronymic: {self.patronymic},\n"
          f"Birthday: {self.birthday}, Phone: {self.phone}, id: {self.id},\n"
          f"Code: {self.code}, Salary: {self.salary}")
```

Вопрос: нужно ли мне создавать отдельно объект класса People, а затем отдельно класса Employees для корректного вывода?

Comment: Тот вывод для Employees будет работать, а для People -- нет, т.к. у Employees в printer есть свои поля. ЗЫ похоже ошибка копипасты в строках с `self.shelve`

Comment: До печати там далеко ещё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class People:

    def __init__(self, surname, name, patronymic, birthday, phone):

        self.surname = surname
        self.name = name
        self.patronymic = patronymic
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.phone = phone

    def printer(self):
        print(f"Surname: {self.surname}, Name: {self.name}, Patronymic: 
{self.patronymic},\n"
      f"Birthday: {self.birthday},\n",f"Phone: {self.phone}") 

class Employees(People):
   def__init__(self,surname,name,patronymic,birthday,phone,position,salary):

        super().__init__(surname, name, patronymic, birthday, phone)


        self.position = position
        self.salary = salary

        self.printer = lambda:  print(f"Surname :
           {self.surname},Name{self.name}, 
           Patronymic: {self.patronymic},\n"
           f"Birthday: {self.birthday},\n",f"Phone: 
           {self.phone},\n",f"Position: 
           {self.position},\n", f"Salary: {self.salary}")





people = People('Иванов','Иван ','Иванович','23.03.1993','87777777777')
people.printer()
print()
employees=Employees('Иванов','Иван','Иванович','23.03.1993','87777777777','программист','1000$')
employees.printer()
```

Comment: Тогда уж: `self.printer = lambda: print(...)`. В текущей записи в `self.printer = print(...` будет результат выполнения print

Comment: Там что вопрос что код чёрт ногу сломит я показал наследование и переопределение метода у меня заработал код

Comment: gil9red и да вы правы с вашим замечанием